# Android studio creating a settings page

Tags: android, android-studio

I am slightly new to Android studio and have the following code for a settings page using a fragment. I used a settingsFragment and settingsActivity to create the settings page. I also created a button in the mainActivity that should take me to the settings page. But whenever I run it, the app just closes. Im not sure how to fix this. Could somebody please take a look?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.settingspagecs309;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openSettingsActivity();
            }
        });
    }


   public void openSettingsActivity(){
       Intent intent=new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open settings"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

SettingsFragment.java:

```
package com.example.settingspagecs309;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

import androidx.preference.Preference;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences,rootKey);
        Preference myPref= (Preference) findPreference("Contact_Preference");
        myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SettingsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.settingspagecs309;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new SettingsFragment()).commit();

        ActionBar menu=getSupportActionBar();
        menu.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        menu.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the error message it is showing:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.settingspagecs309, PID: 29462
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.settingspagecs309/com.example.settingspagecs309.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(androidx.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.preference.Preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(androidx.preference.Preference$OnPreferenceClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.settingspagecs309.SettingsFragment.onCreatePreferences(SettingsFragment.java:22)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:228)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1277)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2535) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29462 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Check your logcat in android studio, there you can see why your app is crashing. Or you can share your crash error here

Comment: What's the Issue ? Please share the Logcat Logs for proper debugging

Comment: I have added the error that it is showing above.